# Python Pandas : Rows as columns with duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv, which looks like this :

```
    location         date        people_vaccinated
0   Afghanistan   2021-02-22          1225
1   Afghanistan   2021-02-23          1145
2   Afghanistan   2021-02-24          2212
3   Algeria       2021-02-22          1120
4   Algeria       2021-02-23          1824
5   Algeria       2021-02-24          1998
```

I need the following:

```
                 2021-02-22  2021-02-23  2021-02-24
   Afghanistan      1225        1145        2212
   Algeria          1120        1824        1998
```

Tried with 'transpose' and 'stack' but it does not exactly what I want.

Comment: use `pivot` for this problem

Comment: `df.pivot(index='location', columns=['date'], values=['people_vaccinated']).reset_index()` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pivot`:

```
res = df.pivot(index='location', columns=['date'], values=['people_vaccinated'])
##### to convert in the given format ####
res.columns = res.columns.droplevel()
res.columns.name = ''
res = res.reset_index()
```

---

```
    location        2021-02-22  2021-02-23  2021-02-24
0   Afghanistan     1225        1145        2212
1   Algeria         1120        1824        1998
```